# How can I assign an xml typed variable and take advantage of the automatic escaping of invalid characters?

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008

How can I take advantage of sql server's automatic escaping invalid characters while assigning to an xml typed variable?

This query escapes and invalid character correctly.

```
SELECT TestCharacter "MyCharacter"
    FROM (SELECT 'An element with normal text and an invalid character: ' + CAST(0x1B00 AS NVARCHAR(128)) AS TestCharacter
) MyTable
FOR XML AUTO ,ELEMENTS

<MyTable>
    <MyCharacter>An element with normal text and an invalid character: &#x1B;</MyCharacter>
</MyTable>
```

This fails:

```
-- This fails:
DECLARE @xml XML = ( 
    SELECT TestCharacter "MyCharacter"
        FROM (SELECT 'An element with normal text and an invalid character: ' + CAST(0x1B00 AS NVARCHAR(128)) AS TestCharacter
) MyTable
  FOR XML AUTO ,ELEMENTS
)

XML parsing: line 1, character 28, illegal xml character
```

Comment: when i open the XML file in the first output in chrome, it still gives invalid character error. are you sure &#x1B is correct?

Comment: Run in MSSQLMS it works. Are you missing the semi-colon?

Answer (score 0):

`&#x1B` is not a valid character in XML.

**In XML 1.0 [(specs)](http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml-20060816/#charsets):**

```
Char ::= #x9 | #xA | #xD | [#x20-#xD7FF] | [#xE000-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#x10FFFF]
```

**In XML 1.1 [(specs)](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#charsets):**

```
Char ::= [#x1-#xD7FF] | [#xE000-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#x10FFFF]
```

`#x1B` (the `escape` character) isn't valid on either list. The fact that `FOR XML` successfully entitized it is a [documented behavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500235.aspx):

> SQL Server entitizes invalid XML characters when they are returned
>   within FOR XML queries that do not use the TYPE directive.
>
> **Although XML 1.0 conformant parsers raise parse errors regardless of
>   whether these characters are entitized or not**, the entitized form is
>   better aligned with XML 1.1. The entitized form is also potentially
>   better aligned with future versions of the XML standard. Additionally,
>   it makes debugging simpler, because the code point of the invalid
>   character becomes visible.

### Solution

If you want to preserve these characters in the XML, you must convert it to Base64 encoding:

**Encode**:

```
DECLARE @xml xml = 
(
    SELECT CAST(TestCharacter AS varbinary(max)) AS MyCharacter
        FROM (SELECT 'An element with normal text and an invalid character: ' + CAST(0x1B00 AS NVARCHAR(128)) AS TestCharacter
    ) MyTable
    FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS, TYPE, BINARY BASE64
)
```

This will encode the string in Base64, and you get an XML that looks like this:

```
<MyTable>
  <MyCharacter>QQBuACAAZQBsA...</MyCharacter>
</MyTable>
```

**Decode:**

```
SELECT CAST(@xml.value('(/MyTable/MyCharacter)[1]','varbinary(max)') AS nvarchar(max))
```